# How can i accessing the web page's HTTP request Headers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one IOS application and pass token in request header while open my webview. I want this request header token while my site load.

Answer (score 1):

Request headers used to load the HTML document the JS is running inside are not exposed to that JS.

You'll need to get the data some other way (such as having the server echo the data back in `data-*` attribute or passing it in from outside the webview).

Comment: Could you please provide example or refrence ?